# HTML textbox masking or validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have textboxes in my html page that I want to accept 2 digits before and after the decimal point. How can I do it in html or javascript?

Sample values are:

```
02.50
10.25
00.00
```

**Code:**

```
function inputControl(input,format)
{
    var value=input.val();
    var values=value.split("");
    var update="";
    var transition="";
    if (format=='int'){
        expression=/^([0-9])$/;
        finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-9]*)$/;
    }
    else if (format=='float')
    {
        var expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,\.]/;
        var finalExpression=/^([1-9][0-3]*[,\.]?\d{0,2})$/;
    }   
    for(id in values)
    {           
        if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!='')
        {
            transition+=''+values[id].replace(',','.');
            if(finalExpression.test(transition)==true)
            {
                update+=''+values[id].replace(',','.');
            }
        }
    }
    input.val(update);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Uuvb/39/

Comment: Is there something wrong with your code?

Comment: I want the digits before the decimal point to be just 2 digits.

Comment: [*Repeats the previous item exactly `n` times*: `{n} where n is an integer >= 1`. Produces `a{3} matches aaa`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instate of spliting every digit and decimal, 
you can try this as below:

```
//1st Make value to string:
value = value.toString();

//2nd Split the digit and decimal:
var values=value.split(".");

//3rd Getting Digit & Decimal in String Form & converting back to integer
var Digit = Number(values[0]);
var Decimal = Number(values[1]);
```

Reference:

1. Convert String To Number: [ClickHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)
2. Convert Number To String: [ClickHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)